# Issue in tflite based estimator model loading on Android device

Tags: android, tensorflow

I generated a Boosted Trees Estimator on structured data and tried to use that estimator to predict on a mobile device. But I am facing the issue, that App generates following error in Android Studio when I start the app.

```
2020-09-30 12:26:34.892 8966-8966/com.example.tflitetest W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal error: Unexpected failure when preparing tensor allocations: Encountered unresolved custom op: ParseExampleV2.
2020-09-30 12:26:34.892 8966-8966/com.example.tflitetest W/System.err: Node number 0 (ParseExampleV2) failed to prepare.
```

I followed this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/estimator) for estimator training, code highlighted below:

```
  tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec([input_column]))

estimator_base_path = os.path.join(tmpdir, 'from_estimator')
estimator_path = estimator.export_saved_model(estimator_base_path, serving_input_fn)
```

(If I am doing something wrong, kindly let me know about it.)

All data files (training/testing data, sample Android app and .tflite models) are available on the following link of Google Drive:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-qDhCJGNZyqu_-XoMyW0kvimyiDdMndO?usp=sharing

Edit1: Usage of Parse Example is included in question.

Comment: do you have a "parse_example" layer in your training ?

Comment: I have revised the question to include the usage of "parse_example" in my estimator training.